# Bar Chart in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, charts

I'm new in JavaFx and i want to display a Bar Chart after choosing a date (for the SQL query) and clicking the button "display chart". I'm wondering if it is possible to display the chart in the same Tab Pane where the button is. What should i write in my button listener? Can anyone help me?
If this is possible, i want also to use the progress indicator while waiting for the result.

[image: the User Interface description]

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: i'll integrate javafx in jframe it seems to be easier. if you want have a look at this: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1564917/java/interfaces-graphiques-java/javafx/integration-code-javafx-jpanel-swing/

Comment: It's not, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but I'll try to address some of the questions you raised.

> I'm wondering if it is possible to display the chart in the same Tab Pane where the button is.

Yes, that seems to be what the sample image you provided is already doing.

> What should i write in my button listener?

The code to fetch the chart data and display the chart.  If you have trouble writing this, you should create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which replicates just the specific thing which is going wrong.

> If this is possible, i want also to use the progress indicator while waiting for the result.

See the [sample code here](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4957967), which is a "Sample for accessing a local database from JavaFX using concurrent tasks for database operations so that the UI remains responsive."  The sample makes use of a progress indicator.

*Aside:* For future questions, you might benefit from just asking a single question in a question, providing some source code which replicates any issue you have, subdividing your problem into parts and asking a specific question on just one particular part you are having an issue with (for example displaying items in a bar chart could be a different question from asynchronously retrieving items from a database).